# Filter non-digits from string

Tags: swift, string, numbers

Using only swift code I cant figure out how to take "(555) 555-5555" and return only the numeric values and get "5555555555".  I need to remove all the parentheses, white spaces, and the dash.  The only examples I can find are in objective-C and they seem to all use the .trim() method.  It appears as though swift doesn't have this method but it does have the .stringByTrimmingCharacters method, but that only seems to trim the white spaces before and after the data.

Comment: None of the "trim" methods will work since they only remove character from the ends of the string.

Answer (score 131):

**Swift 3 & 4**

```
extension String {
    var digits: String {
        return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
            .joined()
    }
}
```

**Swift 5**

You should be able to omit `return`

**Also:**
Read the comment from @onmyway133 for a word of caution

Comment: `return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()`

Comment: Note that `decimalDigits` may contain more than just numbers https://ravron.com/2019/07/how-many-decimal-digits-are-there-anyways/

Answer (score 65):

Split the string by non-digit characters to an array of digits and the join them back to a string:

**Swift 1:**

```
let stringArray = origString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
    NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
let newString = NSArray(array: stringArray).componentsJoinedByString("")
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let stringArray = origString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
    NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
let newString = stringArray.joinWithSeparator("")
```

**Swift 3 & 4:**

```
let newString = origString
    .components(separatedBy:CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
    .joined()
```

Comment: Nice thinking inverting decimalDigitCharacterSet.

Comment: This saved me some time, as a suggestion, the second line can be replaced by simply stringArray.joinWithSeperator("")

Comment: does not filter out '&' or '$' !

Answer (score 22):

I like regular expressions:

```
var s = "(555) 555-5555"
s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
    "\\D", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, 
    range: s.startIndex..<s.endIndex)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One small addition: I found that a better regex to use is `[^\\d+]`, leaving the valid + character intact.

Answer (score 15):

In Swift 4 the solution is more nice:

```
import Foundation

let sourceText = "+5 (555) 555-5555"

let allowedCharset = CharacterSet
    .decimalDigits
    .union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+"))

let filteredText = String(sourceText.unicodeScalars.filter(allowedCharset.contains))

print(filteredText) // +55555555555
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is @Tapani's Swift 2.0 answer as a handy String extension, (length property is not part of solution but I left it in example because it is also handy):

```
import Foundation

extension String {

    var length : Int {
        return self.characters.count
    }

    func digitsOnly() -> String{
        let stringArray = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
            NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
        let newString = stringArray.joinWithSeparator("")

        return newString
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let phone = "(123)-123 - 1234"
print(phone.digitsOnly())
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue but I needed to retain the decimal points. I tweaked the top answer to this:

```
extension String {

    /// Returns a string with all non-numeric characters removed
    public var numericString: String {
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted
        return components(separatedBy: characterSet)
            .joined()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Details

- Xcode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Solution

```
import Foundation

extension String {

    private func filterCharacters(unicodeScalarsFilter closure: (UnicodeScalar) -> Bool) -> String {
        return String(String.UnicodeScalarView(unicodeScalars.filter { closure($0) }))
    }

    private func filterCharacters(definedIn charSets: [CharacterSet], unicodeScalarsFilter: (CharacterSet, UnicodeScalar) -> Bool) -> String {
        if charSets.isEmpty { return self }
        let charSet = charSets.reduce(CharacterSet()) { return $0.union($1) }
        return filterCharacters { unicodeScalarsFilter(charSet, $0) }
    }

    func removeCharacters(charSets: [CharacterSet]) -> String { return filterCharacters(definedIn: charSets) { !$0.contains($1) } }
    func removeCharacters(charSet: CharacterSet) -> String { return removeCharacters(charSets: [charSet]) }

    func onlyCharacters(charSets: [CharacterSet]) -> String { return filterCharacters(definedIn: charSets) { $0.contains($1) } }
    func onlyCharacters(charSet: CharacterSet) -> String { return onlyCharacters(charSets: [charSet]) }
}
```

### Usage

```
let string = "23f45gdor#@%#i425v wer 24 1+DWEJwi 3u09ru49w*()9uE2R_)$I#Q)_ U383q04+RFJO{dgnkvlj b`kefl;nwdl qsa`WKFSA,.E"
print("original string:                                 \(string)")
print("only .decimalDigits:                             \(string.onlyCharacters(charSet: .decimalDigits))")
print("only [.lowercaseLetters, .symbols]:              \(string.onlyCharacters(charSets: [.lowercaseLetters, .symbols]))")
print("remove .letters:                                 \(string.removeCharacters(charSet: .letters))")
print("remove [.decimalDigits, .lowercaseLetters]:      \(string.removeCharacters(charSets: [.decimalDigits, .lowercaseLetters]))")
```

### Result

```
original string:                                 23f45gdor#@%#i425v wer 24 1+DWEJwi 3u09ru49w*()9uE2R_)$I#Q)_ U383q04+RFJO{dgnkvlj b`kefl;nwdl qsa`WKFSA,.E
only .decimalDigits:                             2345425241309499238304
only [.lowercaseLetters, .symbols]:              fgdorivwer+wiuruwu$q+dgnkvljb`keflnwdlqsa`
remove .letters:                                 2345#@%#425  24 1+ 30949*()92_)$#)_ 38304+{ `; `,.
remove [.decimalDigits, .lowercaseLetters]:      #@%#   +DWEJ *()ER_)$I#Q)_ U+RFJO{ `; `WKFSA,.E
```

---

### (Optional) String extension

```
extension String {
    var onlyDigits: String { return onlyCharacters(charSets: [.decimalDigits]) }
    var onlyLetters: String { return onlyCharacters(charSets: [.letters]) }
}
```

### (Optional) String extension usage

```
let string = "23f45gdor#@%#i425v wer 24 1+DWEJwi 3u09ru49w*()9uE2R_)$I#Q)_ U383q04+RFJO{dgnkvlj b`kefl;nwdl qsa`WKFSA,.E"
print("original string:     \(string)")
print(".onlyDigits:         \(string.onlyDigits)")
print(".onlyLetters:        \(string.onlyLetters)")
```

### (Optional) String extension usage result

```
original string:     23f45gdor#@%#i425v wer 24 1+DWEJwi 3u09ru49w*()9uE2R_)$I#Q)_ U383q04+RFJO{dgnkvlj b`kefl;nwdl qsa`WKFSA,.E
.onlyDigits:         2345425241309499238304
.onlyLetters:        fgdorivwerDWEJwiuruwuERIQUqRFJOdgnkvljbkeflnwdlqsaWKFSAE
```

Comment: Thank you Vasily this is a perfect answer and works realy good.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
let string = "(555) 555-5555"
let digitString = string.filter { ("0"..."9").contains($0) }
print(digitString) // 5555555555
```

Putting in extension:

```
extension String {
    var digitString: String { filter { ("0"..."9").contains($0) } }
}

print("(555) 555-5555".digitString) // 5555555555
```

Comment: how simple and elegant, best answer out here! even shorter would be `string.filter(("0"..."9").contains)`

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use NSCharacterSet:

Check out this NSHipster link for Swift and Obj-C implementations:
http://nshipster.com/nscharacterset/

Similar example:

```
var string = "  Lorem    ipsum dolar   sit  amet. "

let components = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()).filter({!isEmpty($0)})

string = join(" ", components)
```

See: **punctuationCharacterSet**

Description:

Returns a character set containing the characters in the category of Punctuation.
Informally, this set is the set of all non-whitespace characters used to separate linguistic units in scripts, such as periods, dashes, parentheses, and so on.

> [@Tapani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3244548/tapani) Makes a great suggestion: `NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet`

Answer (score 1):

Here is @Tapani Swift 3.2 solution

```
let phno = contact.phoneNumbers[0].phoneNumber
let strarr = phno.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
let newString = NSArray(array: strarr).componentsJoined(by: "")
print(newString)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the best solution with filter function. Please have a look into it.

```
let string = "(555) 555-5555"

let onlyDigits = string.filter({ (char) -> Bool in

    if Int("\(char)") != nil {

        return true
    }
    else {

        return false
    }

})
```

Comment: `let onlyDigits = string.filter{ Int("\($0)") != nil }`

Comment: let onlyDigits = string.filter{ch in "0123456789".contains(ch)}

Comment: @altimes this will increase the runtime complexity.

Comment: Interesting thought.  I was assuming that the parsing and constructing an Int would be more complex.   But then, looking at it, it only has a single character to work on which probably has some simple manipulation of the of the ascii value under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly answered but it looks like a number.
I used URLComponents to build the url because it strips out parenthesis and dashes automatically:

```swift
var telUrl: URL? {
    var component = URLComponents()
    component.scheme = "tel"
    component.path = "+49 (123) 1234 - 56789"
    return component.url
}
```

then

```swift
UIApplication.shared.open(telUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

calls **+49 123 123456789**

Answer (score 0):

The character set `.decimalDigits` does not contain only the ASCII digits 0-9, but also for example the following characters: "१᠑⅚㊈๒".

I find it much better to use the following code:

```
extension String {
    var digitsOnly: String {
        filter { $0.isNumber && $0.isASCII }
    }
}
```