# Swift 3 Trimming characters

Tags: swift, swift3, trim

Anyone know how to Trim or eliminate characters from string? I have a data from UIlabel like "ABCDE1000001" and I need to get the numbers only. Any idea? trimming? concat? any other solution?

I also try this but looking for other solution

```
 let cardtrim = String.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABCDEF"))
```

Comment: What if the input is `A1B2C3` ? What if there are no digits at all?

Comment: Check my solution, it filters everything except the numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code works perfectly, but you need to call it on the String variable in which you store the value you want to trim.

```
let stringToTrim = "ABCDE1000001"
let cardtrim = stringToTrim.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABCDEF")) //value: 1000001
```

A more generic solution is to use `CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted` to only keep the digits from the String.

```
let cardtrim = stringToTrim.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
```

Be aware that `trimmingCharacters` only removes the characters in the characterset from the beginning and end of the String, so if you have a String like `ABC101A101` and want to remove all letters from it, you'll have to use a different approach (for instance regular expressions).

Comment: This ***is not the best solution***.  In different locales, you have no idea what might be in "decimal digits".  For example - does it include the "." ?

Comment: @Fattie `CharacterSet` uses Unicode specifications, so all of its subsets are locale independent AFAIK.

Comment: You know I really appreciate what you're saying, @DávidPásztor - but it's just **too risky** in a real world, practical team situation.  The fact is, **you simply want this .. "[^0-9]"** so the best thing is to type that. There are any number of cases where Apple have totally screwed-up ISO implementations, you know. And the standard could change - whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that `trimmingCharacters` removes only (consecutive) leading or trailing characters which match the character set.

To remove **all** non-numeric characters in a string I recommend regular expression

```
let string = "ABC12DE100YU0001"
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\D", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
// -> "121000001"
```

**Update:**

In Swift 5+ there is a more efficient way:

```
let string = "ABC12DE100YU0001"
var trimmedString = string
trimmedString.removeAll{ !$0.isNumber }
// -> "121000001"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of hardcoding the `charactersIn`, this is a dynamic solution that will work on other variations of `strings` than just `ABCDEF`.

```
extension String {

    var numbersOnly: String {

        let numbers = self.replacingOccurrences(
             of: "[^0-9]",
             with: "",
             options: .regularExpression,
             range:nil)
        return numbers
    }
}

let string = "A77BC66DE1001".numbersOnly // 77661001
```

Comment: You should consider using something like this and not hardcode values. If your string looks different then your code will not work.

Comment: @PenRueda, np. You changed the accepted answer, why if I may ask.

Comment: I actually tried it, but didnt work. so for now I used the other solution

Comment: @PenRueda, what didn't work? Create a new class and call it `Extensions` add the extension in there and after that on all your string that you want to do this on just call `.numbersOnly` on whatever class.

Comment: This is the only real solution here. Everything else is silly.

Answer (score 2):

You gotta get Swifty:

```
let string = "ABC12DE100YU0001".filter { ("0"..."9").contains($0) }
```

In extension:

```
extension String {

    func filterLetters() -> String {
        return filter { ("0"..."9").contains($0) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This extension will return the digits in a string which is exactly what you need

```
extension String {

    var digits: String {
        return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
            .joined()
    }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971505/filter-non-digits-from-string)