# How do I disable spaces in textfield? - Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to disable space inputs in my username text fields using Swift UI. How would I go about that?

Current code:

```
@State private var username = ""

CustomInputField(imageName: "at.circle.fill", placeholderText: "Username", text: $username)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI validate input in textfields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073146/swiftui-validate-input-in-textfields)

Comment: Is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139877/swift-3-trimming-characters

Comment: neither of them help and are outdated @LouFranco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to create an observable object and filter the spaces every time the string changes. It should be pretty straightforward:

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var usernameManager = UsernameManager()
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0) {
            Text("Username:")
            TextField(
                usernameManager.string,
                text: $usernameManager.string
            )
            .keyboardType(.asciiCapable)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
            .onChange(
                of: usernameManager.string,
                perform: usernameManager.editingChanged
            )
        }.padding(.trailing, 25)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

```
class UsernameManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var string: String = ""
    func editingChanged(_ string: String) {
        self.string = string.filter(\.isWhitespace.negated)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Bool {
    var negated: Bool { !self }
}
```

---